# What does わかるかンなもん mean?

Tags: meaning

What does the phrase わかるかンなもん mean? Is the katakana 'n' for emphasis? What does the 'mon' in the sentence imply, tone-wise or otherwise? I know the verb is from 'wakaru' to understand, but I don't know what the rest means.

Edit: The phrase is written exactly like that, with 'n' in katakana only. Does わかるか**そんな**もん make sense then? If 'ンな' is short for 'そんな'?

Comment: https://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA

Comment: No, the phrase is written as is.

Comment: So would koto = mon in this case?

Comment: I posted an answer, but to be honest, it was a bit surprising that わかるかそんなもん still didn't make sense to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ンな](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA) is a corrupted version of そんな. It sounds a little offensive and is typically used when the speaker is irritated. Ordinary Japanese words don't start with ん, but this is one of the rare exceptions that happen only in slangy Japanese. ン is typically written in katakana, especially in the middle of a sentence (otherwise this would be hard to parse).

- ンなやつ = そんなやつ = such a guy
- ンなこと = そんなこと = such a thing
- ンな場合 = そんな場合 = such a case/situation
- and so on

And もん is simply a corrupted version of もの. So わかるかンなもん is the same as そんなもの(が)わかるか, or "No way I know/understand such a thing!", referring to whatever mentioned in the previous context.